# In django models. How to prepopulate a particular model everytime we do syncdb

Tags: django-models

I have a model .

```
class ConnectCategory(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
description = models.TextField(max_length = 500, blank=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

I want to prepopulate it every time I do syncdb.(Like a initialize function). Is there any way to do it in the model it self. I am new to django , so any pointers will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

["Providing initial data for models"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-data-for-models)

Comment: Hi Ignacio , thanks for the link. I just wanted to know if it was possible in the model itself i.e. without calling another function.T

Comment: Read the first word of my answer again.

Comment: Yes . I saw that. And in the link you provided , it is possible to load initial fixtures i.e. data is loaded at syncdb. So thanks a lot.